# Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\ChatApplication'

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

i had this error when trying to connect to a database in my sqlserver

connection string in web.config:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

i followed some instruction online and i did this -- > went to my server --> right click on security --> add new Login--> click on search and typed -- > `IIS APPPOOL\ChatApplication` inside the textbox --> click on ok

the error occurred when i tired to click on ok in the login section
[image]

can anyone help me in this problem please

Comment: You cannot add Login like that until ChatApplication is listed as a user in your system. Check users in Control Panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Application Pool Identity](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities-and-sql-server-express) you created is *not* a Windows user.

Create a Windows user to use the selected value, or do not search but type the app pool identity yourself: `IIS APPPOOL\ChatApplication`.

Comment: i didn't understand can u provide me a detailed solution please

Comment: shouldn't I change my connection string to accept windows authentication or my connection string is written right ?

Comment: Create new windows user named _ChatApplication_ from **Control Panel->User Accounts** . Then add new login in the database like you were doing earlier.

Comment: @Sora for Login name in the screenshot you posted put `IIS APPPOOL\ChatApplication`, don't search, and click OK.

Comment: @Ricky you don't _have_ to create a Windows user.

Comment: thank you so much . i just copy and past `IIS APPPOOL\ChatApplication` and hit ok and it work .